# Is there a portable water recycling unit?

Tags: recycling, water, electricity, apartment

Is there a portable water recycling unit that one could install in their studio apartment to recycle grey water ? Or which is the smallest grey water recycling unit ? And can't someone just pass the grey water thru their reverse-osmosis filter and reuse the water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Hydraloop water recycling system](https://www.hydraloop.com/) comes closest to what I was thinking of. It won awards at CES 2020 too. I wish it could be a little smaller. I'm sure other similar products will follow soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own filter, I think.

When I was kid my father and I constructed our own filter, everything you need is some sand, 'dust coal' and a couple of stones and wool. You can use a bottle of soda, or something like that.

Put the wool on the 'mouth' of the bottle, then put in the coal, stones and sand. Put another bottle under the will to extract the clean water.

I'm not a native English speaker, and I don't know some words. If you want, I can make a drawing to make it more clear to understand.

Comment: but this won't give you Reverse-osmosis quality water.

Comment: I asked my friend, and he said that to make an reverse osmosis system, is to use sand, pulverized coal, gravel and a pipe (I searched the correct terms. :P). Put the pipe below the gravel. The pipe must go to an container with a germicidal uv lamp (I dunno the correct term for this lamp) than put a pipe with spigot, to get the clean water.

Comment: Is there any video available online...

Comment: After a little search I found a pdf. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmzi63w68xhna9o/DIY.pdf

Comment: My concern with this is I doubt it will remove all of the chemical residue.  A lot depends on what you are putting into the water to make it "grey."